# Same Partial View on Single Page in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have written following partial view by using aspx view engine

```
<%: Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
.Name("datePicker")
.Format(ViewData["dateFormat"].ToString())
.Value(ViewData["dateValue"].ToString())
%>
```

Now on My single page i have used this Partial View twice.
Main Page Contains

```
<%: Html.Partial("DateTimePicker") %>
 Some Code and again Partial View
<%: Html.Partial("DateTimePicker") %>
```

may be Name is same that's why it is not working properly.
How to tackle this Problem?

Actually the Problem is with javascript.

```
div class="t-widget t-datetimepicker">
<div class="t-picker-wrap">
<input id="datePicker" class="t-input" type="text" name="datePicker">
<span class="t-select">
<span class="t-icon t-icon-calendar" title="Open the calendar">Open the calendar</span>
<span class="t-icon t-icon-clock" title="Open the time view">Open the time view</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="t-widget t-datetimepicker">
<div class="t-picker-wrap">
<input id="datePicker" class="t-input" type="text" name="datePicker">
<span class="t-select">
<span class="t-icon t-icon-calendar" title="Open the calendar">Open the calendar</span>
<span class="t-icon t-icon-clock" title="Open the time view">Open the time view</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

that is what Firebug shows me HTML.
Here both the input Id are datePicker that is why java script function not working.
How to get Id dynamically in Partial view.

Comment: what is the problem ?what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you check in the generated markup whether you have 2 DOM elements with the same `id`? This is not allowed.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili actually 1st Date control is working properly. But the second partial view JS not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it would be more appropriate to create a custom html helper, that would receive the name and value as parameters.

Here's a link that will give you a start [Custom helper implementation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: yap that is one way. But i want to achieve this by using Partial View. As we have UserControl in Asp.Net UserControl is equivalent to Partial view.